# Moore–Penrose pseudo-inverse Reference.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, soft-question

I have seen the Wikipedia page on **Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse**. I want to study more about generalized inverse of matrix. Can you provide some best references for this topic? (Self-Study).

Comment: I think Gilbert Strang explains the pseudoinverse clearly, using the four subspaces picture that he likes to emphasize. The pseudoinverse of $A$ takes a vector $b$ as input, then computes the projection of $b$ onto the range of $A$ (call this projection $\hat b$), then returns as output the vector $x$ of least norm such that $Ax= \hat b$. I think that is a great definition of the pseudoinverse because it is conceptual, and there is no strange-looking formula that we must grapple with to understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The generalized matrix inverse**

The Moore-Penrose matrix evolves organically from the process of generalized solutions to linear systems.

Consider the matrix $\mathbf{A}^{m\times n}_{\rho}$ and the data vector $b\in\mathbb{C}^{m}$ and the linear system
$$
 \mathbf{A} x = b.
\tag{1}
$$

---

If the data vector is in the column space of $\mathbf{A}$, that is,
$$
 b\in\color{blue}{\mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A} \right)}
$$
then the solution to the difference equation in (1) is exactly $0$:
$$ 
 \lVert \mathbf{A} x - b \rVert = 0.
\tag{2}
$$
Hence the appellation "exact solution".

The figure shows an example where
$$
\mathbf{A} =
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
The row space is envisioned as a regular grid. The action of $\mathbf{A}$ on this grid produces the image of the column space.
[image: map]

---

Next, look at the case where the data vector has $\color{blue}{range}$ and $\color{red}{null}$ space components:
$$
  b = \color{blue}{b_{\mathcal{R}}} + \color{red}{b_{\mathcal{N}}}
$$
[![1d][2]][2]
The data vector can no longer be described as a linear combination of the column vectors of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and 
$$
 \lVert \mathbf{A} x - b \rVert > 0
$$
_Generalize_ the concept of solution from "exactly $0$" to "as small as possible." The immediate question is how to measure the size of the residual error, that is, what norm should be used?

A natural and popular choice is the $2-$norm, the familiar norm of Pythagorus. This generalized solution, the least squares solution, is defined as
$$
 x_{LS} = \left\{
 x\in\mathbb{C}^{n} \colon
\lVert
 \mathbf{A} x - b
\rVert_{2}^{2}
\text{ is minimized}
\right\}
$$

---

How to compute the solution? Use the singular value decomposition to resolve the $\color{blue}{range}$ and $\color{red}{null}$ space components. The SVD is
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} &=
  \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*} \\
%
 &=
% U 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cccc|cc}
     \sigma_{1} & 0 & \dots &  &   & \dots &  0 \\
     0 & \sigma_{2}  \\
     \vdots && \ddots \\
       & & & \sigma_{\rho} \\\hline
       & & & & 0 & \\
     \vdots &&&&&\ddots \\
     0 & & &   &   &  & 0 \\
  \end{array} \right]
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  \\[5pt]
%
  & =
% U
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S}_{\rho\times \rho} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% V
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$
The total error can be decomposed into
$$
\begin{align}
  r^{2} = \lVert
 \mathbf{A} x - b
\rVert_{2}^{2} = 
\big\lVert
 \Sigma\, \mathbf{V}^{*} x - \mathbf{U}^{*} b
\big\rVert_{2}^{2}
&=
\Bigg\lVert
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \mathbf{S} \\
    \mathbf{0}
  \end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} 
  \end{array}
\right]
%
x - 
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\[6pt]
    \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array}
\right]
b
\Bigg\rVert_{2}^{2} \\
  &=
\big\lVert
\mathbf{S}
\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} x - 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} b
\big\rVert_{2}^{2}
+
\big\lVert
\color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*} b
\big\rVert_{2}^{2}
\end{align}
$$
The total error is minimized when
$$
\mathbf{S}\,
\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} x - 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} b
=
0
$$
This is precisely the pseudoinverse solution
$$
\color{blue}{x_{LS}} = 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}
\mathbf{S}^{-1}
\color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*}b
=
\color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{+}}b.
$$
$$
\boxed{
 \mathbf{A}^{+} = \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}
\mathbf{S}^{-1}
\color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}^{*}}
}
$$

---

Read more
[Singular value decomposition proof][3], [Solution to least squares problem using Singular Value decomposition][4], [How does the SVD solve the least squares problem?][5]

The original paper by Penrose [A generalized inverse for matrices](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/John_Gower2/publication/261591739_Generalized_Inverse_Matrices/links/565d73dd08ae1ef929826f55.pdf) is an enjoyable read.
[image: penrose]

A succinct and illuminating discussion is given by Laub in [Matrix Analysis for Scientists and Engineers](http://bookstore.siam.org/ot91/)
[image: ch 4]
Excerpt:
[image: excerpt]

[11]:

Comment: In the final conclusion (the formula in box), it should be $\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal R}^*$. A $*$ is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a bit of literature study on this: [Discussion of an Article by X.Mary: Generalized Inverses and Green's Relations](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/274893572_Discussion_of_an_Article_by_XMary_Generalized_Inverses_and_Green%27s_Relations).