# If $A$ is a non-square matrix with orthonormal columns, what is $A^+$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares, pseudoinverse

If a matrix has orthonormal columns, they must be linearly independent, so $A^+ = (A^T A)^{−1} A^T$ . Also, the fact that its columns are orthonormal gives $A^T A = I$. Therefore,

$$A^+ = (A^T A)^{−1} A^T = (I)^{-1}A^T = A^T$$

Thus, $A^+ = A^T$. Am I correct? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, and you can say more $A^+=A^T=A^{-1}$

Comment: @Mesmerizedstudent: A is non-square so it has no inverse.

Comment: @AndreasH. oh, I missed it. Of course you are right.

Answer (score 2):

### Problem statement

Start with a matrix $$A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$$ where $m>n$, and
a valid statement for the pseudoinverse matrix
$$
 \mathbf{A}^{+} = \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{A}^{*}
$$
We know (see links) that this matrix is a *left inverse*:
$$
 \mathbf{A}^{+} \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{I}_{n}
\tag{1}
$$

If we add the constrain that the column vectors of $\mathbf{A}$ are orthonormal, we also have
$$
 \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{I}_{n}
\tag{2}
$$

### Conclusion

The results $(1)$ and $(2)$ suggest the identity
$$
 \mathbf{A}^{+} \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{I}_{n} = \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A}
$$
from which we conclude that
$$
\mathbf{A}^{+} = \mathbf{A}^{*} 
$$

### Example

$$
 \mathbf{A} = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left[
\begin{array}{cr}
 i & -1 \\
 i &  1 \\
 0 &  0 \\
\end{array}
\right], 
\qquad
\mathbf{A}^{*} = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrc}
 -i & -i & 0 \\
 -1 &  1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

---

$$
 \mathbf{A}^{+} \mathbf{A} =
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right] = \mathbf{I}_{2}, 
\qquad
\mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^{+} =
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\ne \mathbf{I}_{3}
$$

---

$$
 \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} =
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right] = \mathbf{I}_{2}, 
\qquad
\mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^{*} =
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\ne \mathbf{I}_{3}
$$

---

**Background reading**

Categorize the pseudoinverse matrix in terms of left and right inverses:
 [generalized inverse of a matrix and convergence for singular matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241296/generalized-inverse-of-a-matrix-and-convergence-for-singular-matrix/2242261#2242261), [What forms does the Moore-Penrose inverse take under systems with full rank, full column rank, and full row rank?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537880/what-forms-does-the-moore-penrose-inverse-take-under-systems-with-full-rank-ful/2200203#2200203)

General properties of the pseudoinverse matrix: [Moore–Penrose pseudo-inverse Reference.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2141966/moore-penrose-pseudo-inverse-reference/2258257#2258257)

Comment: Note that for the expression of the pseudoinverse to be correct, $A$ has to be full column rank (this is true for a matrix with orthonormal columns).

Answer (score 0):

The *pseudoinverse* $\rm A^+$ must satisfy $4$ conditions:

- $\rm A A^+ A = A$
- $\rm A^+ A A^+ = A^+$
- $\rm (A A^+)^* = A A^+$
- $\rm (A^+ A)^* = A^+ A$

Let us verify that $\color{blue}{\rm A^+ = A^\top}$. The first two conditions are satisfied because

$$\rm A A^+ A = A \underbrace{\left( A^\top A \right)}_{=I} = A$$

and

$$\rm A^+ A A^+ = \underbrace{\left( A^\top A \right)}_{=I} A^\top = A^\top = A^+$$

and the last two conditions are trivially satisfied if $\rm A$ is a *real* matrix.

Answer (score 0):

> *If the real matrix $A$ has a left inverse, then $A^+=(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$.*

Note that $A^TA$ being invertible is equivalent to $A$ having a left inverse.

If the columns of $A$ are orthonormal, then $A^TA=I$ and therefore $A^+=A^T$.

The initial statement is just a verification of the required properties for the pseudoinverse.

---

Suppose on the contrary that $A^+=A^T$. Consider $A=QR$, where $Q$ has orthonormal columns and $R$ has a right inverse (such a decomposition can be easily derived from the Gram-Schmidt algorithm). Then, by general theory,
$$
A^+=R^+Q^+=R^T(RR^T)^{-1}Q^T=A^T=R^TQ^T
$$
If we multiply by $Q$, we obtain $R^T(RR^T)^{-1}=R^T$ and therefore
$$
RR^T=I
$$
Thus $A$ is the product of a matrix with orthonormal columns and a matrix with orthonormal rows (the transpose of a matrix with orthonormal columns, if you prefer).

Comment: Excellent answer congratulation